# PHP buildback with DB2 extension and SSL for bluemix

Tags: php, db2, ibm-cloud, buildpack

Is there a PHP buildpack out there which I can use which has the DB2 extensions and the SSL for the DB2. I have been searching for it and tried using the [PHP Buildpack](https://github.com/ibmdb/php-buildpack), but with no luck to connect to the DB2.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested that but you should be able to use the standard PHP builpack that comes with IBM Cloud and its Cloud Foundry.

The [PHP buildpack allows to configure extensions](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/php/gsg-php-config.html) to be downloaded. If you [add `ibm_db2.so` as extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ibm-db2.setup.php), it should be considered as it is part of the regular PHP ecosystem. Another Db2 driver is [PDO_IBM](https://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_IBM).

Comment: Thank you. But I did test with this build pack. But I was unable to connect. Also are you aware of changes need to be done for SSL? New to php and not a lot of material out there for bluemix integration.

Comment: I have just added a connection to a ssl enabled database (db2) on php and deployed it on bluemix to see if I am able to connect. Like a simple proof of concept. It will return success or failure accordingly. Locally it returns success, but in bluemix it fails because of SSL. The buildpack I specified helps me establish the connection.